# Modifying a regular expression by another by adding a something to it

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to modifying my regex expression using replace. What ultimately want to do is to add **01/** in the front of my existing pattern.It is litterally replacing a pattern by another.
Here is what I am doing with replace:

```
 df['found_d'].str.replace(pattern2, '1/'+pattern2)
 #must be str, not _sre.SRE_Pattern
```

I would like to use **sub** it takes 3 arguments and I am not too sure of how to use it at this point. 
Here is an expected input:

```
 df['found_d']= 01/07/91 or 01/07/1991
```

I need to add a missing date to my pattern.

Comment: `df['found_d'].str = '01/' +  df['found_d'].str`?

Comment: Can you post input and expected output?

Comment: @OlvinRoght I think you got the right idea. I dunno why I am only focusing on regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for callables, `re` provides dedicated means to access the matched text during replacement.

In order to append a literal `01/` to a pattern match, use a `\g<0>` unambiguous backreference to the whole pattern in the replacement pattern rather than using the regex pattern:

```
df['found_d'] = df['found_d'].str.replace(pattern2, r'01/\g<0>')
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Fantastic. that \g<0> is amazing. I did not know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 0.20, pandas `str.replace` can accept a callable that will receive a match object. For example if a column has a pattern of 2 uppercase letters followed with 2 decimal digits and you would want to reverse them with a colon between, you could use:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{2})',
                                  lamdba m: "{}:{}".format(m.group(2), m.group(1)))
```

It gives you the full power of the `re` module inside pandas, changing here `'AB12'` with `'12:AB'`

Comment: Great. I  did not think of using a lambda expression there

Comment: I'll try the logic. In here , those numbers are not existing my original expression. I am adding it to it.

Comment: @Herc01: This is an unrelated example. To give a regex that meet your requirement, I need an example or input strings and their expected output.